# How do I construct a doubly connected edge list given a set of line segments?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computational-geometry, doubly-connected-edge-list

> For a given planar graph $G(V,E)$ embedded in the plane, defined by a set of line segments $E= \left \{ e_1,...,e_m \right \} $, each segment $e_i$ is represented by its endpoints $\left \{ L_i,R_i \right \}$. Construct a DCEL data structure for the planar subdivision, describe an algorithm, prove it's  correctness and show the complexity.

According to [this description of the DCEL data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCEL), there are many connections between different objects (i.e. vertices, edges and faces) of the DCEL. So, a DCEL seems to be difficult to build and maintain.

Do you know of any efficient algorithm which can be used to construct a DCEL data structure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Data structure (conventions consistent with [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list)):

```
struct half_edge;

struct vertex {
    struct half_edge *rep;  /* rep->tail == this */
};

struct face {
    struct half_edge *rep;  /* rep->left == this */
};

struct half_edge {
    struct half_edge *prev;  /* prev->next == this */
    struct half_edge *next;  /* next->prev == this */
    struct half_edge *twin;  /* twin->twin == this */
    struct vertex *tail;     /* twin->next->tail == tail &&
                                prev->twin->tail == tail */
    struct face *left;       /* prev->left == left && next->left == left */
};
```

> #### Algorithm
>
> 1. For each endpoint, create a *vertex*.
> 2. For each input segment, create two *half-edges*, and assign their tail vertices and twins.
> 3. For each endpoint, sort the half-edges whose tail vertex is that endpoint in clockwise order.
> 4. For every pair of half-edges `e1, e2` in clockwise order, assign `e1->twin->next = e2` and `e2->prev = e1->twin`.
> 5. Pick one of the half-edges and assign it as the representative for the endpoint. (Degenerate case: if there's only one half-edge `e` in the sorted list, `set e->twin->next = e` and `e->prev = e->twin`). The next pointers are a
>      permutation on half-edges.
> 6. For every cycle, allocate and assign a *face* structure.

Comment: Basically a bunch of gnarly bookkeeping. This is probably why textbook authors are reluctant to go into detail.