# How to find vertices of bounded region made by intersection of lines

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Suppose we have random lines made with 2 points. and point has (x,y)

For example:

[image: this is sample image which i am looking for]

Now when we draw a random line you will see many lines intersect with each other. This eventually gives rise to bounded regions. How to find the vertex points for each bounded region?

**My approach**:
First we find all the intersection points of the various lines. In some cases multiple lines intersect at the same point.

However I am not sure how to pick the points that make up a bounded region.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please share your approach to the problem. This is not a site for solving your homework. Also try to post questions about the algorithm underlying a question, instead of solutions in specific languages.

Comment: Hi i am looking for how to do. it's step. or how can i do it looking for suggestion. i think i should add little more what i am trying.

Comment: When you say line, do you mean a [line segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment)? It seems segments are used in your picture. Also, do you want to find the 'bounding points' for _all_ regions at once, or only for a _single_ specified region?

Comment: I guess OP means a line segment since he is specifying a pair of points, and wants to find the bounding points for all regions at once.

Comment: @Amrit have a look at this: https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/10120/10120_S17/Topic22_3p2_Galvin_2017_short.pdf

Comment: @Sagnik A pair of points is also probably the most natural way of specifying a line. However, the diagram seems to make it clear that they're line segments.

Comment: Hi, Yes they are Line Segment, made with 2 points. and i would like to find it all at once.

Comment: Thank you all,  i see that contain had changed and correct my grammar too.  feel really good and happy. many many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding the all the vertices for *all* of the bounding regions is roughly the same amount of work as creating a *doubly connected edge list* (DCEL) that represents your regions, so I will show how to construct a DCEL from a set of line segments. After that, finding all the boundary points for each region from a DCEL is a simple operation.

First, we find all line segment intersections between the segments we start with. This can be done efficiently with the standard [sweepline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) algorithm for line segment intersection, which is described in various references, such as in [these slides](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/panos/cg13/l03.pdf). This can be done in $O(n\log n + K)$ time, where $n$ is the number of line segments and $K$ the number of intersections between these lines.

For the next part, we construct a set of endpoints $P$ and a set of line segments $L$, where for each segment $l\in L$, we also store the pair of points $(p,q)$ from $P$ that are the endpoints of segment $l$. First, add all original line segments to $l$ and the corresponding endpoints to $P$.

Then, at every intersection point $p$, split the segments that intersect at that point into two segments 'separated' by $p$, store the point $p$ in the set $P$, remove the old segment from $L$ and add the new segments to $L$, setting their endpoints accordingly.

In the end, we have represented our regions with a graph $G=(P,L)$, where the vertex set $P$ are all points in our 2D space (including the intersection points) and the set of edges $L$ contains all segments connecting these points. Note that the graph $G$ doesn't have any crossing edges by construction, so it is *planar*.

From this planar graph, we can construct a DCEL, as [shown in this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2516), which is mostly bookkeeping.

In the DCEL, each region is associated with a representative half-edge. From that half-edge, we can find all half-edges that form the border of the region. Then, the vertices of the region are all vertices of those half-edges.

---

It is possible to skip the DCEL and find the vertices directly, but likely you need to do almost the same thing. The main advantage of using a DCEL as an intermediate step is that someone else already has made an algorithm to construct a DCEL.