# Vertices/segments graph to polygons

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

[image]

On a 2D plane there is a set of vertices V and segments S.
Each segment has 2 vertices, and each vertex knows segments that use it.
That creates a kind of a graph.

**I would like to find all polygons as is depicted above.** A polygon P is a set of n segments.

I tried [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) for each vertex with first cycle detection and duplicates removing. It unfortunately doesn't work for specific cases, for example it won't find P5 on picture below.

[image]

Comment: You should represent the segments by directed half-edges as in a [DCEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list), so that each region is represented by the half-edges on its boundary. Then an appropriate search over the edges will find all enclosed polygonal regions.

Comment: Your problem is a simpler version of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/90880/how-to-find-vertices-of-bounded-region-made-by-intersection-of-lines , but the answer there does not go into the details on how to perform the final search.